# Does not including details of a national identity card affect a UK tourist visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, tourist-visas

I have applied for a UK tourist visa and was confused by the question  "do you have a national identity card".

I was issued an Aadhar card few years back which could be considered a national identity card but it does not have an expiry date. Since the question asked for an issue date and expiry date I replied no.

Will this affect my visa? I have already gone to the UK once on a tourism visa. Should I cancel the application and reapply?

Comment: What can you do with this card?

Comment: What did you answer in your previous application? If you’re concerned about it, mention the Aadhar card in the free format ‘other comments’ section at the end of the application.

Answer (score 2):

I did not provide National ID (Aadhar), instead I filled my passport number there and it was accepted. I got my visa without any issues.

Note that its not the universal case. According to Indian government, Aadhar is still not technically mandatory. So, UK govenment can't just reject the visa citing I don't have an Aadhar card. I was an NRI when I got the visa. Aadhar compliance is lower among NRIs. That could also be the reason. (For example, NRIC/FIN is mandatory for a Singapore resident/citizen. If you are a Singaporean, you have to provide NRIC without any exceptions).

If you have an Aadhar, its better to add that.